# How to pass object when calling public plugin method in Jquery

Tags: jquery, plugins

I'm building a jQuery plugin that will have a couple of public methods inside it. This is how it looks right now.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.ajDialogue = function (options) {

        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.ajDialogue.defaults, options);

        return this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $.fn.ajDialogue.show();
        });

    };

    $.fn.ajDialogue.show = function () {
        // code
    };

    $.fn.ajDialogue.destroy = function () {
        console.log(this);
        // 'this' is this plugin
    };

    $.fn.ajDialogue.defaults = {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        onShow: function () { },
        onDestroy: function () { }
    };


})(jQuery);
```

I'm declaring and running the plugin like this, which works fine.

```
var $myPluginElement = $('body').ajDialogue();
```

But when I do this

```
$myPluginElement.ajDialogue.destroy();
```

I don't get $myPluginElement passed to the public method. As I commented the console only outputs 'this'  as the whole plugin, not the $myPluginElement. Like this

```
function (options) {

        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.ajDialogue.defaults, options);

        return this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $.fn.ajDialogue.show();
        });
}
```

Am I thinking wrong and what do I need to do to be able to have public methods that gets the element sent along?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a strange way to do things, I usually do something like this :

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.ajDialogue = function (options) {
        var defaults = {
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                onShow: function () { },
                onDestroy: function () { }
            },
            self = this,
            opts = $.extend(defaults, options);

        this.show = function() {
            console.log(this);
        }
        this.destroy = function() {
            console.log('destroy');
        }

        return this.each(function () {
            self.show()
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

var $myPluginElement = $('body').ajDialogue();

$myPluginElement.show();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xQaRA/)

Comment: Yeah I know, I tried a new way, from this blog http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/. Didn't quite get it to work as I wanted. With this way it feels more like the way I'm used to write classes/code with public and private methods. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

i am not a jQuery plugin pro or whatever ... anyway i make things like this happen like so

```
<span id="test"></span>


(function ($) {
$.fn.ajDialogue = function (options) {

    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.ajDialogue.defaults, options);

    return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $.fn.ajDialogue.show();
    });

};

$.fn.ajDialogue.show = function () {
    // code
};

$.fn.ajDialogue.destroy = function (element) {
    alert(element);
    // 'this' is this plugin
};

$.fn.ajDialogue.defaults = {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    onShow: function () { },
    onDestroy: function () { }
};


})(jQuery);


$(window).ajDialogue.destroy($('#test'));
```

working js fiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/delueg/dfLTH/)